# when i send data in json format in laravel 5.8 I receive them by axios but it doesnt show anything in vue template by v-for

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, show, v-for

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 mt-2">
            <label> category </label>
            <select name="categories" class="form-control" multiple>
                <option v-for="category in categories" :value="category.id"> {{category.name}} </option>
            </select>
        </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-left"> ذخیره</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
             
                categories: []
            }
        },
        props: ['brands'],
        mounted() {
            axios.get('/administrator/Products/categories').then(response =>{
               this.categories = response.data.categories
               console.log(response.data.categories);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })

        },methods: {
            },
           
        }

    }
</script>
```

data recieved by axios and assigned to categories variable but i cant show them in select box in template
data in json format response correctly from controller in laravel to vue and I can see them in console when I put "console.log(response.data.categories)" code but I dont know why categories name dont exist in category select box

Answer (score 1):

"this" in "this.categories" will point to the response function and not Vue app. You should use your Vue global app name in nested functions like this.